# Cannot create static sitemaps on nextjs with next-sitemap - undefined sitemap.xml

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xml, next.js, xml-sitemap

The sitemap files generated using [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-sitemap?activeTab=readme) with NextJS - have undefined as their site URL. It's not even capturing the priority etc. It seems that the config file isn't loading at all.

To Reproduce -
Here is a direct link to the sandbox reproduction

- [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/stupefied-joliot-gspwwt?file=%2Fpackage.json)

Expected behavior -
Expected to get example.com as the siteUrl

Here are the screenshots of the package.json and config file and the output-

[image: package.json]

[image: sitemap-config]

[image]